# Next.js SSG page component gets new object from props every time it renders

Tags: next.js

I'm using Next.js and i want to build simple SSG page, which take immutable data from db on build time and render it to some list of elements. For that purpose i'm using getStaticProps. Here's source code of this page:

```
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import utilStyles from '../global-styles/utils.module.css'
import { getSortedPostsData } from '../utils/posts'
import { useMemo } from 'react'

const Home = ({ allPostsData }) => {
  const posts = useMemo(() => {
    console.log('useMemo log');
    return allPostsData.map(({ id, date, title }) => (
      <li className={utilStyles.listItem} key={id}>
        {title}
        <br />
        {id}
        <br />
        {date}
      </li>
    ))
  }, [allPostsData])

  return (
    <Layout home>
      <ul className={utilStyles.list}>
        {posts}
      </ul>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  console.log('getStaticProps run')
  const allPostsData = await getSortedPostsData()

  return {
    props: {
      allPostsData
    }
  }
}

export default Home
```

In production build I can see 'getStaticProps run' log once in console. All required data gets from database and passes to Home component in props. This component renders posts list fine. When i  switch to this page in my browser first time I can see exactly one 'useMemo log' in the console. But...

Every time I switch to another page and then back to Home page I see another 'useMemo log' in the browser console too. I'm not understand why this is happening. This page loaded exactly once (not on every page switch). Data for this page is obtained exactly once (in build time). But Next.js passes new array (array with new address) in Home page props every time it renders. Why this is happening and how can i avoid this behavior to memoize my posts list and not render it every time I switch the page?

Comment: The `Home` component will re-render when a client-side navigation to it occurs, that's expected behaviour.

Comment: My question is not why Home component was rerendered. My question is why allPostsData array has a new referece at rerender. In simple React app (not Next) if i have Home component and it was rerendered for some reason the refereces of objects from props will not change. In Next.js for some reason it works not like that.